# not able to open terminator in bash windows 10

Tags: gnome-terminator, windows-subsystem-for-linux

When opening terminator from my bash Windows 10, I am getting this error

```
/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0/gtk/__init__.py:57: GtkWarning: could not open display
  warnings.warn(str(e), _gtk.Warning)
You need to run terminator in an X environment. Make sure $DISPLAY is properly set
```

Comment: Possibly related: [run a graphical web browser on windows subsystem for linux?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/330760/65304)

Answer (score 2):

I've done following steps when approached same problem

1. Install VcXsrv for windows and run it.
2. Open bash on windows and run `echo "export DISPLAY=:0" >> $HOME/.bashrc`
3. for changes of `.bashrc` file to get append run `source $HOME/.bashrc`
4. after that you can run `terminator -u` and use it

Answer (score -1):

First, install xvfb on your server. Assuming you are using `apt-get`:

```
sudo apt-get install xvfb
```

Now, run the xvfb service at a custom display number, like:

```
sudo Xvfb :5
```

After that, you can run any application that requires `X`inside your virtual frame buffer by exporting the display number and running your application:

```
export DISPLAY=:5
run_my_application
```

The `DISPLAY` is set only for the current terminal session, so keep that in mind when implementing automation for this step.

Answer (score -1):

I solved that problem downloading **MobaXterm** and I just ran the same using this tool and it works.

[image]

My bash contains:

```
bash -c -l "DISPLAY=:0 terminator -x bash -c 'cd .; cd ../../mnt/c/Users/User/Desktop/; zsh; exec bash' &"
```